# SQL Query that does opposite of cross join

Tags: mysql

In MS SQL server, I have a table with 3 columns -- Name, WeekDay, Bread.
This Table has name of a person, WeekDay(1 to 7 representing sunday, monday, tuesday and so on) and number of breads ate.

I want a query that outputs
Name   MonBread(Breads ate on monday)       TuesBread(Breads ate on Tues) and so on.

For one name A, there will be 7 rows in the table each having data which represents breads ate on each weekday.
Output should display one row for one person A with 7 columns having number of breads ate on each day.

Please help.

Comment: Post your schema and sample data, or better yet, an SQL Fiddle, and show what you've tried, and where you're having trouble.

Comment: Greetings. I see you're new on stackoverflow. Please post examples of your code or your question will be voted down to oblivion.

Comment: And you mention MSSQL in your question, but you've tagged it MySQL. Which is it?

Comment: Make a lookup table that has WeekDayId and WeekDayName.  Then look into a PIVOT.  Please post your attempts if you have more questions.